# How do I add qtreeview sub items

Tags: qt, pyside, qtreeview

How can I add children to my current qtreeview items in the code i provided below? I want it to look something like this:

[image]

The code below creates a treeview that is sorted but im not entirely clear on how to add children items. Hope you can help, thanks.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class SortModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SortModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)

        if leftData:
            leftData = leftData.lower()
        if rightData:
            rightData = rightData.lower()

        print('L:', leftData, 'R:', rightData)
        return leftData < rightData


class Browser(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Browser, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(200, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Assets')
        self.setModal(True)

        self.results = ""

        self.uiItems = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.uiItems.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.uiItems.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.uiItems.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiItems.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiItems.header().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self._model = self.create_model(self)
        self._spmodel = SortModel(self)
        self._spmodel.setSourceModel(self._model)
        self._spmodel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.uiItems.setModel(self._spmodel)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.uiItems, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.uiItems.doubleClicked.connect(self.doubleClickedItem)
        self.show()

    def doubleClickedItem(self, item):
        name = item.data(role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        print name

    def create_model(self, parent):

        items = [
            'Cookie dough',
            'Hummus',
            'Spaghetti',
            'Dal makhani',
            'Chocolate whipped cream'
        ]

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name'])

        for item in items:
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(item))


        return model

    def showEvent(self, event):
        geom = self.frameGeometry()
        geom.moveCenter(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.setGeometry(geom)
        super(Browser, self).showEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            # self.hide()
            self.close()
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(Browser, self).keyPressEvent(event)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Browser()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this in your create_model method. There are several different ways of appending child rows and columns. Instead of passing a QStandardItem directly to model.appendRow, create it and save it in a variable. Then you can use QStandardItem.appendRow to add children to your top level rows.

I don't know Python and may get the syntax wrong, but the basic pattern is something like this:

```
std_item = QtGui.QStandardItem ("Dinner")
child_std_item = QtGui.QStandardItem ("Drinks")
std_item.appendRow (child_std_item)
```

Alternately, you can do this at the model level using model.insertRow and specify the QModelIndex of the parent item. You can get the QModelIndex of an item using model.indexFromItem. Hopefully that's enough to get you going. Each QStandardItem knows its parent, if any, and its children, so it's usually a matter of having the parent available to add/change/remove children.